# Choosing a polynomial for CRC

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory

CRC checksum is a homomorphism from polynomials over $\mathbb F_2$ to itself. As I understand, the map $f\mapsto g$ it is simply remainder from division $f$ by $p$, where $p$ is a fixed polynomial for the checksum.

I see that in general use $p$ is not arbitrary for a fixed degree. But how such $p$ are choosen?

Comment: There is more discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/8346/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically irreducible. There's always $n$ with $X^n\equiv 1\pmod p$, and one wants to maximize $n$. If $p$ is irreducible of degree $d$, then $\mathbb F_2[X]/(p)$ is a finite field with $2^d$ elements, hence its multiplicative group is cyclic of order $n=2^d-1$ (and this $n$ is the smallest $n$ with $X^n\equiv 1$).

**EDIT:** I had overlooked the fact that the above conditins do not yet guarantee that the cyclic group is in fact generated by $X$ itself. See the comments for a more detailed explanation and better criteria. (I would delete this answer if it hadn't been accepted ;) )

Comment: Actually, several of the CRC polynomials of small degree, e.g. CRC-16-CCITT $x^{16} + x^{12} + x^5 + 1$, are _not irreducible_ but of the form $(x+1)p(x)$ where $p(x)$ is a _primitive_ polynomial (that is, irreducible and the roots are generators of the (cyclic) multiplicative group of the field). This allows for detection of double errors. More recently chosen CRC polynomials such as CRC-32 are primitive polynomials. As to _how_ such polynomials are chosen, see the references in [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) of CRC polynomials

Comment: @DilipSarwate: IMHO this should be promoted to an answer.

Comment: Hagen, I'm sure you know this, but adding the remark just in case. The polynomial $p$ being irreducible of degree $d$ does not guarantee that $n=2^d-1$ is the smallest $n$ with the property $x^n\equiv 1$. The easiest counterexample is the irreducible polynomial $p(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ that clearly has the property $x^5\equiv 1\pmod {p(x)}$. When this happens for $n<2^d-1$ the maximum length of a data block that can be protected by such a CRC is consequently reduced. For this reason *primitive* polynomials play a key role.