# Why or why not use an irreducible polynomial for a cyclic redundancy check?

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cyclic-groups

I understand the need for using an irreducible polynomial for a prime power finite field when doing multiplication with numbers in those fields. For certain applications, such as the Q parity bytes used in RAID6, a non-zero number should have a multiplicative inverse which might fail if it can be multiplied by another non-zero number in that field and yield zero. However, I don't fully understand its importance in its use with cyclic redundancy checks. This seems to be a bit different scenario because instead of working with numbers inside the field, your taking a message that represents a number that's generally much, much larger than the field and dividing it down to fit in the field. After that, your pretty close to been done with the CRC with maybe a an XOR to complete the job.

As a counter example, I discovered that the polynomial used for the CRC32 on CD-ROM is composed of two smaller polynomial: $(x^{16} + x^{15} + x^2 + 1) \cdot (x^{16} + x^2 + x + 1)$.

Maybe the a question I need to ask is a why would they use a reducible polynomial in this case rather than a known irreducible one?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on cyclic redundancy checks seems to discuss this issue in the section titled "Designing Polynomials". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Comment: Interesting, a quote from that article gives an interesting hint to the answer of my question: "A common misconception is that the "best" CRC polynomials are derived from either irreducible polynomials or irreducible polynomials times the factor 1 + x, which adds to the code the ability to detect all errors affecting an odd number of bits.[7] In reality, all the factors described above should enter into the selection of the polynomial and may lead to a reducible polynomial."

Comment: I don't claim to understand the finer points of CRC-polynomial selection but in your example I am actually a bit worried about the presence of that double zero $x=1$ (a root of both factors).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8346/11619) for a bit more. I think you can relatively safely just skim my answer (while I do know some coding theory and cyclic codes in particular, CRC-polynomial selection also has criteria beyond just minimum Hamming weight of a non-catchable error). Do check out the links!

Comment: @Jyrki My example isn't just a polynomial I picked, it's what's specified in the ECMA-300 standard for encoding data sectors on a CD. I would assume it was well picked for that purpose, but I don't fully understand why. I think it's partly due to catching certain categories of burst errors and that the data being is only 16384 bits (2048 bytes) which is within the range of a 16-bit CRC's limit.

Comment: @penguin359 I realize that. I'm sure they had good reasons. Undoubtedly they also wanted the CRC-polynomial to have a degree that's a multiple of 16 (if not 32). I just find it curious. Also, when the CD-format was specified, the people designing these specs had more experience with magnetic recording and such. It may have shown at some points (though, being competent folks, they were aware of some of the differences between magnetic and optical media). I cannot point at anything particular for I'm not an expert on either. It's just an impression I got.

Comment: For example, I have always wondered why the CD microcode uses runlength limited codes. At least the explanations (those that I have seen) for having run-lengths limited only seemed to apply to magnetic recording. I am prepared to be wrong about this (but IIRC some changes came to the DVD-standard here somewhat in support of my hunch). But it is just a hunch.

Comment: @Jyrki Sorry if that sound critical, but I'm also surprised about the polynomial having such a root per the standard. Thanks for the link! Slowly thing are becoming clearer.

Comment: Didn't souond critical at all! I apologize for trying to sound as if I knew this stuff. What may have happened (what could easily have happened) is that they wanted the CRC to detect all patterns of less than five bit errors within a block of size $<2^{15}-1$. So they look up a pair of suitable irreducible polynomials of degree fifteen. Then they, all in line with the usual practice, throw in a factor $(x+1)$ to detect all odd weight error patterns. At which point they notice that their CRC has 31 check bits.

Comment: (cont'd) Nobody protectes data in chunks that are not full bytes, so there's nothing else to do but repeat that factor $x+1$. The presence of that common factor means that you cannot check divisibility by the two sixteen degree factors separately and be happy. But, that is unlikely to harm the use of this standard in any significant way. And having that extra factor does reduce the probability of undetected error anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you want to transmit a polynomial $M(x)$, but the recipient receives a slightly different polynomial $M'(x)$. We can define the "error polynomial":

$$E(x)=M'(x)-M(x)$$

Call the CRC-polyomial $P$. Then an error will go undetected iff $P$ divides $E$, or in other words if every divisor of $P$ is also a divisor of $E$. We can therefore guarantee that certain kinds of errors get caught by analysing the divisors of $P$ and $E$. Here are a few simple examples:

$E(x)=x^{n+m}+x^{n+m-1}+...+x^n=x^n(x^m+x^{m-1}+...+1)$, a burst error, ie. $m+1$ flipped bits in a row. This will be caught if $P$ has nonzero constant term (so it has no common divisors with $x^n$) and is of degree greater than $m$ (since it then cannot divide a polynomial of degree $m$).

$E(1)=1$, ie. an odd number of flipped bits. This will be caught if $x+1$ divides $P(x)$, since then $P(1)=0$.

$E(x) = x^{n+m} + x^m=x^n(x^m+1)$, ie. two flipped bits $m$ bits appart. This will be caught if $P$ is a multiple of a primitive polynomial of order greater than $m$. So a primitive polynomial of degree $d$ will catch two errors if they are less than $2^d-1$ bits appart.

So in short, using a reducible polynomial may indeed be desirable if you want to guarantee certain kinds of errors get caught.